# How do I use wave.open without using files?

Tags: python

I can download a `.wav` file from the internet with this code

```
request = requests.post('https://example.com/ambience.wav')
```

but now I want to load it to `wave.open` without ever writing a file because the machine I'll be running this script doesn't have any physical storage, I only have terrabytes of RAM, how do I do this?

Comment: `wave.open` accepts a file-like object like `io.BytesIO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `io`

```
import io
import requests
import wave

response = requests.post('https://example.com/ambience.wav')
data = io.BytesIO(response.content)
w = wave.open(data)
```